# Parsing access.log squid proxy

Tags: windows, shell-scripting, windows-command-prompt

I have logs files, access.log-*, and I need exclude the 'TCP-DENY' (or include only the 'TCP-MISS').

How I parsing, like grep command on linux,  access.log file on windows?

On linux it is work fine. I need doing it on windows script (bash).

Thanks

Comment: Get out of CMD, and switch over to powershell.  Powerhsell has lots of functionality for filtering text.  http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/feature/Filtering-output-from-Windows-PowerShell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Zoredache, PowerShell is the way to go. However I think the command you want is

```
findstr <string>
```

Please note findstr *is* case sensitive.